# AdaptiveTrigger does not work in custom templated control UWP

Tags: uwp, custom-controls, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, visualstatemanager

I have two `VisualStateGroups` in my `Style`. It works fine but when I adjust the windows width,  the `AdaptiveVisualStateGroup` does not get triggered. What am I missing?

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExpandPanel">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExpandPanel">
                <Grid>                        
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDesktop">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderText.(UIElement.Visibility)" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.25"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Margin="3" x:Name="ExpandCollapseGrid" Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image x:Name="ImageIcon" Width="{TemplateBinding IconWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding IconHeight}" Source="{TemplateBinding IconSource}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="FontIcon" Glyph="{TemplateBinding Glyph}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding HeaderFontSize}" Margin="8" />
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding HeaderFontSize}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="ExpandCollapseButton" 
                                              Width="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonWidth}" 
                                              Height="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonHeight}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonMargin}">
                                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform"
                                                      Data="M 0 40 L 40 20 L 0 0 Z"  
                                                      Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateButtonTransform"/>
                                    </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="Content" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. There's no need to create another group. The following works for me

```
<Style TargetType="local:ExpandPanel">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ExpandPanel">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ViewStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.25"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="1" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="180" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RotateButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" To="0" Duration="0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NarrowDesktop">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NarrowMinWidth}"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <!--  TODO: change properties for narrow view  -->
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderText.(UIElement.Visibility)" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NormalDesktop">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource NormalMinWidth}"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <!--  TODO: change properties for normal view  -->
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderText.(UIElement.Visibility)" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="WideDesktop">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <!--  TODO: change properties for wide view  -->
                                    <Setter Target="HeaderText.(UIElement.Visibility)" Value="Visible" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid Margin="3" x:Name="ExpandCollapseGrid" Background="Transparent">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image x:Name="ImageIcon" Width="{TemplateBinding IconWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding IconHeight}" Source="{TemplateBinding IconSource}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                                    <FontIcon x:Name="FontIcon" Glyph="{TemplateBinding Glyph}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding HeaderFontSize}" Margin="8" />
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderText" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding HeaderContent}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding HeaderFontSize}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" x:Name="ExpandCollapseButton" 
                                              Width="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonWidth}" 
                                              Height="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonHeight}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding ToggleButtonMargin}">
                                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform"
                                                      Data="M 0 40 L 40 20 L 0 0 Z"  
                                                      Fill="{ThemeResource ToggleSwitchForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateButtonTransform"/>
                                    </ToggleButton.RenderTransform>
                                </ToggleButton>
                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" x:Name="Content" RenderTransformOrigin="1,0.5">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```